# Prestashop JS file not loaded

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to load one javascript file to head from module in **Prestashop 1.6.1.1**. But it's not loaded, help me to get reasen of this issue.

***localhost/modules/***

[image]

***miniwa.php***

```
public function hookDisplayHeader() {
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/miniwa.css', 'all'); // LOADING
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/showgame.css', 'all'); // LOADING
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'js/showgame.js'); // NOT LOADING !!
}
```

**CSS files are loading properly.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load any js in your module then that js file should be in your module folder like:

```
your_module_name/views/js/front/js_file_name.js
```

If you want to load js in your front controller then `your_module_name/views/js/front/js_file_name.js` otherwise if you want to load it in admin then it should be like `your_module_name/views/js/admin/js_file_name.js`

Now in your php file you write like:

miniwa.php

```
public function hookDisplayHeader() {
   $this->context->controller->addJs($this->_path . 'views/js/front/showgame.js');
    $this->context->controller->addJs($this->_path . 'views/js/admin/showgame.js');
}
```